# Upload file functionality not working in Ubuntu

Tags: php, linux, apache-flex, ubuntu

I have made a Flex+PHP based application in which there is a functionality to upload a picture to the server. The application uploads a picture fine if run on Windows. But on Ubuntu, file is not getting upload at all. Can it be permissions related issue?

Here is the log maintained while uploading a file:

```
Uploading 5408_1243356204478_1246540615_30751024_3730562_n.jpg...
File opened
File upload in progress (349 of 31340)
File upload in progress (349 of 31340)
File upload in progress (31340 of 31340)
File upload in progress (31340 of 31340)
File upload in progress (31340 of 31340)
File upload in progress (31340 of 31340)
File upload in progress (31340 of 31340)
File upload in progress (31340 of 31340)
File upload in progress (31340 of 31340)
File upload in progress (31340 of 31340)
HTTP error occured - 
HTTP IO error occured -
```

> Also, I tried this app on an OpenSuSE
>   machine and the uploading just worked
>   fine there.

My application's path: /var/www/bin-release
Permissions of /var/www/bin-release/*****

owner,group = baltusaj,www-data
files,directories = 777,777

I have also added baltusaj to the www-data group in /etc/group

The HTTP I/O error is still there, dancing around my nerves. :(

Comment: You could check your `phpinfo()` to see where it's trying to put temp files and make sure the permissions are correct there.

Comment: Checked it out. tmp folder was not set. I set it to /tmp whose permissions are rightly set but the problem persists. Same HTTP IO error occuring which does not occur if this app is run on OpenSuSE.

Comment: And did you restart apache after changing the settings? What does the PHP error log say (with error_reporting set to E_ALL)? Does the file end up in /tmp or not?

Comment: Yes I did. /var/log/apache2/error.log isn't showing anything useful or related to my app. The file does not end up in /tmp

Comment: is it because of different type of directory separator in windows(\) and linux(/) ?

Comment: Nopes. As I said the app works fine on another distribution of Linux i.e. OpenSuSE. I am not using the diectory separators at all i.e. I want the files to get uploaded to the director in which upload.php is residing.

Comment: what are the configurations regarding file uploads in your php configuration file? maybe they differ between the two setups?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for trying to help. :)

I replaced following line

```
public var uploadFile:String = "upload.php";
```

with

```
public var uploadFile:String = "http://localhost/bin-release/upload.php";
```

which made the app work on Ubuntu. It was working on OpenSuSE with just 'upload.php' too though.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend running Wireshark from the client side to capture the network traffic as the file is attepted for upload.  This should allow for an effective view of what the server is actually doing between the two installations.

http://www.wireshark.org/

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue in Flex + Java in Mac Safari browser. I fixed it using the urlRequestVariable and altering the response from services.Hope that might help you.

**Solution**:**1. Create an urlRequest variable and set the file upload URL.**

For example, var request:URLRequest=new URLRequest();
request.url=http://localhost:8080/projectContext/upload/";

**2.Use URLVariables to set the request data**
[Now REST interface and userObject is the queryparam]

```
var sendVars:URLVariables=new URLVariables(); 
            var user:Object = new Object; 
            user.firstName ="XXX"; 
            user.lastName="YYY"; 
            sendVars.userObject = user; request.data=sendVars;

            var _refUploadFile:FileReference=new FileReference(); 
            _refUploadFile=obj.file;
            _refUploadFile.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onUploadProgress);
            _refUploadFile.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onUploadIoError); 
            _refUploadFile.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, onUploadSecurityError); 
            _refUploadFile.upload(request, "file", true); 
            _refUploadFile.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onUploadComplete);
```

From the services I tried returning a response object and the onUploadComplete method was never called, thought the file was uploaded successfully.So when you return a String from the service onUploadComplete method will be called.